# Integrated Exchange login with GWT on Tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat, exchange-server, single-sign-on

I have a GWT app to deploy to Tomcat on a Windows server, with the following requirements:

1- The app should work fully, whether the user is in the Windows domain or not;

2- If the user *happens to be* in the domain, the app should be able to identify the user in some manner. Presumably, this should be via getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteUser(), but any other alternative is fine...

3- If the user *happens to be* in the domain, the app should be able to access the MS Exchange server in that domain, without requiring the user to enter their password.

I've scoured the web high and low for this, but unfortunately, it seems there's no way to *get* authentication without *forcing* authentication. There are many examples of exclusions for, say, a login form or other "public" resources, but that won't work for us, since all the resources in a GWT app are packed into the same "page".

Maybe it's my limited understanding that's making me fail in some basic way, but I've tried to look at JCIFS, Jespa, Waffle and SPNEGO, and I just can't seem to get working the way I want to...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
J.

Comment: i think that this 2 links can really help you because i do not think that GWT is really popular ... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gwt-platform https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-web-toolkit

Comment: I... have no idea what that means. The app is already mostly done, and it's in GWT. Whether it's popular or not is entirely beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a Javascript on your front page and have a Kerberos/SPNEGO protected page.  The javascript will attempt to request a protected page,  if the user is on the domain you will get the correct result from the page otherwise you will get 401 access denied.  In the former case you can redirect your browser to exchange page,  or have another AJAX call to retrieve things from exchange server in the later case you either show a log-in form or a generic anonymous page.

Comment: I confirm Kerberos is the best option because it allows token delegation from browser to Tomcat and from Tomcat to Exchange. Not so easy of course but other ways would be ugly or unsecure.

Comment: No, I can't do redirects and such. It's a GWT application. However, I suppose I can have a dummy protected resource which calls a "side" service. The problem then becomes, how to get the 401 from non-domain users, instead of having the browser attempt to negotiate on its own, and displaying its own login dialog.

Comment: You can do it Mozilla by setting mozbackgroundrequest property on the XmlHTTPRequest object.  There is some discussion how to do it with Chrome here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31582 not sure what you'll do with IE or Safari.

Comment: I don't have access to the XmlHTTPRequest object. It's a GWT application.

Answer (score 0):

What about using JNI to call the Win32Api function LogonUser?
By doing impersonation at the thread level you will have the NTLM token added to the current thread and you would be able to call exchange with no issues

Comment: No, that doesn't really help. LogonUser requires me to have the user's password. Plus, it has nothing to do with getting Tomcat to find out whether the user is in the domain or not, and who the user is. I understand I have to add a filter of some sort in order to get Tomcat to authenticate the user, but all the filters I've tried have failed at step 1 of the question...

Comment: Are you using IIS as the web server and tomcat as the application server? If so, you can try this procedure www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=8&page=1 it will run tomcat using iis security settings, so you can skip the domain issues that way

Comment: I wasn't, but I can. Thanks for the link. Doesn't really tell me how the Java app can figure out who the user is, but, one step at a time, right?